# Net Read Timeout error appears after click action in Selenium Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am automating my application using Selenium Ruby.The application has a 'Add Files' button to attach files. On clicking it, a system modal popup to Upload Files is displayed.However, just after that the code is stuck and i see the error "Error:#'<'Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout'>'" in the console.
Here is the html dom:

```
<div class="row fileupload-buttonbar"> 
    <span data-test-id="button-add-files" class="btn btn-success fileinput-button mq"> 
    <span>Add files...</span>  
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="" data-enterkeydisabled="true">  
    </span>  
    <button data-test-id="button-delete-all-files" type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete mq">Delete All</button>    
</div>
```

The xpath used to get the button is `"//*[@data-test-id='button-add-files']`.
I also tried using the Javascript functions

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",xpath)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success fileinput-button mq')[0].click()")
```

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Use watir which is a nice wrapper to selenium ruby binding . And ask question here by tagging water here.

Comment: Is that the actual HTML, or a typo? Those single quotes around the greater than and less than symbols isn't valid HTML. Also, a net read timeout makes me think it's not even able to access the page. Where's this hosted at, are these tests? Can you describe your setup a little bit more? And are you sure you have the JS hooked up properly that something is attached to the button-add-files span? And is there a reason you aren't clicking the file input/button instead?

Comment: Hi Jay , Yes, its HTML, i have removed the quotes.It is a html web application and i have been automating it in Chrome.I tried using the xpath "//*[@data-test-id='button-add-files']//input[@name='files[]']" to click on that level but it still wouldn't work. What do you mean by "JS hooked up properly ... ", can you please explain?

Comment: Hi All, I have updated the question. The File upload opens up for me now( i didnt do any script update) but Net Read Timeout error shows up after the modal popup appears.